# How to get the MySQL connection from applicaiton.properties in spring boot ireport

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, datasource

Currently I am using this code to generate ireport. But I need to get the datasource directly from the application.properties as I don't want to use the username and password for the sql connection again.

```
        File file = ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:report/collectorInvoice.jrxml");
        InputStream input = new FileInputStream(file);

        // Compile the Jasper report from .jrxml to .japser
        JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(input);

        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/divron?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC","aha","123");

        // Get the parameter
        Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<>();

        parameters.put("invoiceId",id);
        try (Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection()) {

            JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameters, conn);

            // Export the report to a PDF file
            JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint, "D://" +"collectorInvoice -"+ id + ".pdf");

        }
        return new ResponseEntity<Object>(null, HttpStatus.OK);
```

This is the code that should be change.

```
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/divron?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC","aha","123");
```

So please help me to get the whole data from the sql connection without using the username and password of the sql connection again.

Answer (score 0):

If a DataSource is already created by spring boot, you can just Autowired it in your Bean (or use another injecting way) and use a connection from the DataSource

```
@Autowired
DataSource dataSource;
....
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameters, dataSource.getConnection());
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.. to me I have added the     @Autowired
    @Qualifier("dataSource")
    private DataSource dataSource; and works fine